# Weighted press ups for abdomen

Tags: muscle, training, hypertrophy

Loading with weight crunches is no viable because at the end of the movement the weight actually drags you forward making the movement way easier than without weight, it only becomes viable when doing half repetitions of 15% degrees or less so it's more of an abdominal pulse than abdominal crunch.

And doing endless sets of crunches is not an option, after 150 I usually just get bored and give up.

I tried upside down crunches but for some reason the motion is just impossible, I try to crunch my spine but I end up doing a sit up by flexing my hips... almost as if my brain couldn't make the connection in order to understand the movement.

So as an alternative option, are weighted press ups enough to cause abdominal hypertrophy? Or is there a better close chain option?

Planks are excluded by default.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the [cable crunch](https://exrx.net/WeightExercises/RectusAbdominis/CBKneelingCrunch), if the machinery is available to you.

Comment: I can buy a  set of pulleys, I already have weight plates at home.